# Can I use jQuery or javascript to make an <Img> behave like a link without the <a> based on class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a large number of images of the same class "linkImg" and I would like them to behave as links without adding  tags.

What I'm tryng is something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function()
    {
        $('.linkImg').click( function( event )
            {
            var fileSrc = $(this).attr('src');
            fileSrc = fileSrc.slice(fileSrc.lastIndexOf('/')+1,-4); // gets the image file name   
                var linkPath = '_img/largeImg/' + fileSrc + '.jpg';
            var linkRel = 'relValue';
            var linkTarget ='targetValue';
            gotothelinl(linkPath, linkRel, linkTarget)// this is just a made-up function - it the part I don't know how to make work


            })
    } );

</script>
```

When it works it should behave like the tag was there with all attribute intact. I tried using location.href but I can't ad rel or target attributes to that.

thx in advance

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your are taking the problem for another angle... try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


$(function()
    {
        $('.linkImg').each( function()
            {
            var fileSrc = $(this).attr('src');
            fileSrc = fileSrc.slice(fileSrc.lastIndexOf('/')+1,-4); // gets the image file name   
                var linkPath = '_img/largeImg/' + fileSrc + '.jpg';
            var linkRel = 'relValue';
            var linkTarget ='targetValue';
            $(this).wrap('<a href="'+ linkPath +'" target="' + linkTarget + '" rel="'+ linkRel + '" />')


            })
    } );

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - exactly what I wanted to accomplish.

Answer (score 3):

To change the location of the page you'd do

`location.href = "/newLocation.html"`

This simulates a hyperlink (although I'm an ajax enthusiast!)